# Make the return value of a PHP function equal to a javascript variable?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a php function that pull data from the database and return html code which is a code for a drop down menu. What I need to do is append this drop down menu to the div using jQuery. The problem that I am having is how can I assign the return value from php into a jQuery variable?

```
function returnUserNames(){
//open connection to the database

return 'this an html code that should be returned by this function';

}
```

I have tried the following but it is not working.

```
<script>
var menu = <?php echo returnUserNames() ?>;
$('#show_menu').append(menu);
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Put `<?php echo returnUserNames() ?>` in `"`.

Comment: I did add a quote but I get a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string" error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PHP code is generating text that is going directly into a Javascript context, meaning that you have to generate VALID javascript code. As it stands now, your code will produce

```
var menu = this an html code that should be returned by this function;
```

which is an outright javascript syntax error. Never **EVER** directly output text from PHP into a javascript context like this. Always use json_encode() to ensure that whatever you're outputting becomes syntactically valid Javascript, e.g.:

```
var menu = <?php echo json_encode(returnUserNames()) ?>;
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

which will produce:

```
var menu = 'this an html code that should be returned by this function';
```

Note how the `'` quotes were automatically added.

Comment: Thank you. This was the solution :)

Answer (score 2):

You have misspelt **return** and **script**.

```
var menu = <?php echo returnUserNames() ?>;
```

this whole php-script also needs to be enclosed in quotation marks:

```
var menu = "<?php echo returnUserNames() ?>";
```

And your jQuery script shouldn't run until the page is loaded, and `#show_menu` is available.

Comment: Thanks for poiting out the typos. Those are typos in this page and not in the actual script. The error that i get is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string"

Comment: Please always copy and paste the *real* script, don't attempt to re-type it. As you have seen, you can introduce errors that aren't relevant to the question. Marc recommends another approach that wouldn't require the quotes.